# Bazel Starlark: how can I generate a BUILD file procedurally?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, starlark

After downloading an archive throug http_archive I'd like to run a script to generate a BUILD file from the folder structure and Cmake files in it (I currently do that by hand and it is easy enough that it could be scripted). I don't find anything on how to open, read and write files in the starlark documentation but since http_archive itself is loaded from a bzl file (haven't found the source of that file yet though...) and generates BUILD files (by unpacking them from archives) I guess it must be possible to write a wrapper for http_archive that also generates the BUILD file?

Answer (score 6):

This is a perfect use case for a custom [repository rule](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/repository_rules.html). That lets you run arbitrary commands to generate the files for the repository, along with some helpers for common operations like downloading a file over HTTP using the repository cache (if configured). A repository rule conceptually similar to a normal rule, but with much less infrastructure because it's running during the [loading phase](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/concepts.html#evaluation-model) when most of the Bazel infrastructure doesn't apply yet.

The starlark implementation of `http_archive` is [in http.bzl](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/build_defs/repo/http.bzl#L96). The core of it is a single call to [`ctx.download_and_extract`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html#download_and_extract). Your custom rule should do that too. `http_archive` then calls `workspace_and_buildfile` and `patch` from `util.bzl`, which do what they sound like. Instead of `workspace_and_buildfile`, you should call [`ctx.execute`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html#execute) to run your command to generate the BUILD file. You could call `patch` if you want, or skip that functionality if you're not going to use it.

The [repository_ctx](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html) page in the documentation is the top-level reference for everything your repository rule's implementation function can do, if you want to extend it further.

Answer (score 1):

When using [`http_archive`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/repo/http.html#http_archive-name), you can use the `build_file` argument to create a BUILD file. To generate it dynamically, I think you can use the `patch_cmds` argument to run external commands.